# WebDriver.io interceptor Error: TypeError: WebdriverAjax is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

hi try to launch my test with webdriver.io and interceptor service, this is my package.json

package.json

```
  "name": "my-new-project",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.8.8",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.8.8",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.8.7",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.8.7",
    "chromedriver": "^112.0.0",
    "geckodriver": "^3.2.0",
    "msedgedriver": "^91.0.0",
    "nock": "^13.3.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-edgedriver-service": "^2.1.2",
    "wdio-geckodriver-service": "^4.1.1",
    "wdio-intercept-service": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js",
    "test": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js --spec test/specs/test1.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webdriverio": "^8.8.8"
  }
}
```

test1.js

```
import { remote } from 'webdriverio';
import WebdriverAjax from 'wdio-intercept-service'

const WDIO_OPTIONS = {
    port: 9515,
    path: '/',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
}

let browser;
const interceptServiceLauncher = WebdriverAjax();

beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await remote(WDIO_OPTIONS)
    interceptServiceLauncher.before(null, null, browser)
})

beforeEach(async () => {
    interceptServiceLauncher.beforeTest()
})

afterAll(async () => {
    await client.deleteSession()
});

async function time(pause = 1000) {
    const starttime = new Date().getTime();
    await browser.pause(pause);
    const endtime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("-------------------------------->", pause, endtime - starttime); // outputs: 3000
}

describe('Test Case Name', () => {
    it('should intercept and modify a request with Nock', async () => {
        await time(1000);
        browser.url('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
        browser.setupInterceptor(); // capture ajax calls
        browser.expectRequest('GET', '/posts/1', 200); // expect GET request to /api/foo with 200 statusCode
        browser.expectRequest('POST', '/posts/1', 400); // expect POST request to /api/foo with 400 statusCode
        browser.expectRequest('GET', /\/posts\/1/, 200); // can validate a URL with regex, too
        browser.click('#button'); // button that initiates ajax request
        browser.pause(1000); // maybe wait a bit until request is finished
        browser.assertRequests(); // validate the requests

        // browser.url('http://foo.bar')
        // browser.setupInterceptor();
        // browser.click('#button')
        // browser.pause(1000);
        //
        // var request = browser.getRequest(0);
        // assert.equal(request.method, 'GET');
        // assert.equal(request.response.headers['content-length'], '42');
        await time(5000);
    });
});
```

when i start my test with "npm run test" i recive this error

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55425/devtools/browser/0d726522-6a04-4054-820c-b9805dde997a
[0-0] 2023-05-01T08:58:50.200Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
[0-0] `browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
[0-0] Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.
[0-0] Spec file(s): file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/test/specs/test1.js
[0-0] Error: TypeError: WebdriverAjax is not a function
[0-0]     at file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/test/specs/test1.js:13:34
[0-0]     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
[0-0]     at async Promise.all (index 0)
[0-0]     at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
[0-0]     at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15)
[0-0]     at async formattedImport (C:\Users\lbott\node-project\webdriver.io\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:9:14)
[0-0]     at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\Users\lbott\node-project\webdriver.io\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:42:28)
[0-0]     at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\lbott\node-project\webdriver.io\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:100:20)
[0-0]     at async MochaAdapter._loadFiles (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:67:13)
[0-0]     at async MochaAdapter.init (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:62:9)
[0-0]     at MochaAdapter._loadFiles (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:84:35)
[0-0]     at async MochaAdapter.init (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:62:9)
[0-0]     at async Object.adapterFactory.init (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:215:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:72:27)
[0-0]  Error:  Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object that is not fully initialised.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.
Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.
Spec file(s): file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/test/specs/test1.js
Error: TypeError: WebdriverAjax is not a function
    at file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/test/specs/test1.js:13:34
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:533:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15)
    at async formattedImport (C:\Users\lbott\node-project\webdriver.io\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:9:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\Users\lbott\node-project\webdriver.io\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:42:28)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\lbott\node-project\webdriver.io\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:100:20)
    at async MochaAdapter._loadFiles (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:67:13)
    at async MochaAdapter.init (file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/node_modules/@wdio/mocha-framework/build/index.js:62:9)
[0-0] 2023-05-01T08:58:50.201Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
[0-0] 2023-05-01T08:58:50.202Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://localhost:9515/session/694a1cc2893f5838943a559e31adb7cb
[0-0] 2023-05-01T08:58:50.246Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - file:///C:/Users/lbott/node-project/webdriver.io/test/specs/test1.js
2023-05-01T08:58:50.365Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2023-05-01T08:58:50.366Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
```

after 3 days of test, with nightwatch, webdriver.io a think it's not possibile intercept the response and change the data in the response

my prevoius test was

```
describe('Test Case Name', () => {
    it('should intercept and modify a request with Nock', async () => {
        await time(1000);

        // Intercepts the request to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
        nock('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')
            .get('/posts/1')
            .reply(200, { body: 'hello world' });

        await browser.url('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
        await browser.waitUntil(() => {
            return browser.$('body').getText().includes('hello world');
        }, {
            timeout: 5000,
            timeoutMsg: 'expected body to contain "hello world" after 5s',
        });

        await time(5000);
    });
});
```